# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime' to 'string'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datetime

Empiezo con la facturacion 3.3 en mexico pero al momento de tomar la fecha me manda este error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime' to 'string'

Es en esta parte del codigo

```
namespace FacturacionCSharp {
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //llenamos la clase comprobante
            //Damos de alta el comprobante
            Comprobante Ocomprobante = new Comprobante();
            Ocomprobante.Version = "3.3";
            Ocomprobante.Serie = "H";
            Ocomprobante.Folio = "1";
            Ocomprobante.Fecha = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: Puedes indicar por favor la Clase `Comprobante` ?

Comment: intenta DateTime.Now.ToString() y verifica que sea el formato de fecha que buscas.

Comment: @RafaelAcosta la clase comprobante es la misma que anexa el SAT ... la revise y el dato de fecha es un string

Comment: @Jebux tiene razón solo agrega el **`.ToString()`** al final con eso se debe solucionar tu error. si necesitas guardar en un formato diferente o dar un formato a la fecha puedes utilizar la respuesta de Rafael.

Comment: @MiguelZarate me funciono a la perfeccion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con la información que suministras, tu problema está el la conversión de `DateTime` a `string`.

Intenta transformar la fecha actual a `string` de la siguiente manera:

```
Ocomprobante.Fecha = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

***Nota***: Debes tener en cuenta el formato de fecha que la clase Comprobante (SAT) admite. En el ejemplo que te he puesto la fecha sería del tipo **02/10/2019 -> dd/MM/yyyy**. Si necesitas otro formato de fecha, indícalo en los comentarios.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! asi es con esto me funciono, en el anexo 20 de SAT me manda la fecha que debo usarlo, AAAA-MM-DDThh:mm:ss pero con la informacion que me das con eso basta para modificarlo